# Excel crash caused by AddIn UDF

Tags: excel, com, automation, shim

I'm facing a problem where I have a managed Excel AddIn which implements a AutomationServer (UDFs) and also the interface `IDTExtensibility2`. The AddIn uses a native COM Shim written in C++. Everything works like I expect, when the seperate client is running. If the client is not available, whenever the user starts typing a Excel function name, after the first letter, Excel crashes. If our AutomationServer is not loaded, this does not happen. I don't get it why the crash occurs because the functions are not even executed at this stage.

What may be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: You could debug Excel.exe using Visual Studio or WinDbg, and catch all exceptions (including First-Chance ones). Maybe you'll see something, especially if all the binaries where compiled on the machine you debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Simon Mourier's idea, I caught all exceptions when debugging and found after some research that an `ExcelApp.CalculateFull()` in the `OnConnection`-event was messing things up. See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284876/en-us which gave me the final clue to solve things.